# How to say "where else", "who else", or "what else" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

I have looked for some references regarding how to say "where else", "who else", and "what else" but I still can't find one that's dependable enough. Furthermore, it seems like there are quite a lot of ways to express "where else", "who else", "what else".

Here are some example sentences I found on the internet which contain "where else", "who else", and "what else" when translated. I'm sorry that instead of coming with statements, I come with examples. It's because I couldn't find a source that states how to form "where/who/what else. Idk if these sentences are correct though :

1) 还有哪里？

2) 还有什么地方？

3) 我们还能在哪里聊天？

4) 你还会在哪里度假？

5) 别的什么地方我能找到这本书呢？

6) 她还去了别的什么地方？还见了谁？

7) 你还想买些什么，史密斯小姐？

8) 女士，还有其他什么事吗？

9) 你还要点什么菜吗？

10) 聚会上还有谁？

Next, from the sentences above, it seems like when you place 还/别的/其他 or any other words that mean "else" and any question words like 什么，谁，and 哪里 together, you can already form "question word (like where/who/what) + else". I don't know if my assumption is correct though. Please kindly tell me if my assumption is incorrect.

If forming "question word + else" really goes the way I assume it, why is there double else "还&其他" in the 8th sentence? Is it okay to place two "else"s here?

Then, why do some of them contain "有" or "在" and some others not? Is it necessary to add "有/在" when one wants to express "(where/who/what else)? If yes, what do both characters mean/indicate here? And will there be any difference if you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next, from the sentences above, it seems like when you place 还/别的/其他 or any other words that mean "else" and any question words like 什么，谁，and 哪里 together, you can already form "question word (like where/who/what) + else". I don't know if my assumption is correct though. Please kindly tell me if my assumption is incorrect.

Yes, a 'question phrase' can be formed by the way you have discussed.

For example:

你**还**要买**什么**？ - What else do you want?

你**还**要去**哪里**？ - Where else do you want to go?

还有**谁**要**来**？ - Who else still wants to come?

---

谁还 - Who still (want to come)

哪里还 - Where still (want to go)

什么还 - What still (want to buy)

---

In the 8th sentence, '女士，还有其他什么事吗?', it is actually okay to remove the '其他' as it is unnecessary as you said. (double else)

This forms: 女士，还有什么事吗?

---

"有" literally means "have"

"在" literally means "there"

There is not much meaning and explanation to why these two characters are sometimes used and sometimes not. I don't feel like I can fully explain to why this is so as if I did I have a possibility to give wrong advice. If you give me some comparison examples I would be happy to help you explain the differences to why one uses these characters and why one don't.

Comment: You are very welcome.!